# Programmed a keylistener, but it executes everything twice

Tags: python, python-3.x

I programmed a standard keylistener with pynput, but when using `keyboard.type`, it seems like the keys are released twice.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Listener

keyboard = Controller()

def on_release(key):
    print('key {} released'.format(key))
    if key.char == 'a':
        keyboard.type('b')

with Listener(on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

# Pressing 'a' yields:
# 
# key u'a' released
# key u'b' released
# key u'b' released
```

It doesn't seem like the key is pressed twice, only released twice. Is this the intended behavior? If not, what should be done to avoid this?

Comment: It gets even weirder: when I want to print a Unicode character, e.g. capital ß, it does this:

Comment: `code` key '\x08' released
key '\x08' released
key '\x08' released
key 'ẞ' released
key Key.backspace released
key Key.backspace released
key Key.backspace released
key '\x00' released

Comment: Just tried it on a Mac. Almost the same, except now it gives me 'a' released instead of '\x00' released.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help contributors help you

Comment: Go ahead and edit the original question

Comment: Done it, it says "too many characters". Will try again.

Comment: @Bernd I think my answer was wrong, I have a MCVE for this issue. Do you mind if I update your post?

Comment: @Bernd I've updated the post to include a much smaller example that shows the same thing. You can roll it back to the original code if you feel that the new code doesn't appropriately convey your question.

Comment: @JaredGoguen your answer looks reasonable to me... That'd have been my first guess as well...

Comment: I'd also guess that `keyboard.press` (to avoid an automatic `keyboard.release` event) and not `keyboard.type` to avoid the release event will stop the infinite callbacks...

Comment: Having said that... is the key then perputally held down... umm....

Comment: @JonClements Note that 'a' and 'b' are different characters, so it doesn't blow up

Comment: Good point... but still - it may be that just pressing instead of typing may stop the additional release event

Comment: @JonClements It stops both release events, even just doing `keyboard.type('a')` outside of anything, with no additional typing triggered by the `on_release` function will trigger two releases. It seems like two separate events may be being generated, one in `Listener._process` and one in `Listener._on_fake_event`. This behavior doesn't *seem* right, but I don't have to time to fully dive into the source.

Comment: Thank you! I replaced `keyboard.type` by `keyboard.press`, and the additional callbacks stopped! But also the backspacing...?

Comment: Jared, indeed, this 'a' out of nowhere...

Comment: Should we tell the original developer?

Comment: Problem: only `keyboard.type` will make _multiple_ backspacing. All other methods create one backspace and then stop.

Comment: Guys, if we all agree this behavior doesn't seem right, does anybody have the contacts of Moses Palmér, the original developer? He is probably the only one who can fix this...

Comment: See https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/40

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in *pynput*.

As you have noticed, events can reach a `Listener` both from the system and when `Controller`s are invoked. The latter is true only for *Xorg* and *win32*, as they do no propagate synthetic events to listeners.

Or so I thought. It turns out that on *win32*, this is true only for mouse events; keyboard events appear to propagate normally. In any case, I have pushed a proposed solution [here](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/tree/fixup-win32-keyboard-listener).

If you have the opportunity to test it, I would be grateful, otherwise I will merge it into master in a couple of days and make a new release. I only have access to *win32* through *VirtualBox*, so I would appreciate some more bare-metal testing.